# c# how do i refresh items in my listbox

Tags: c#, listbox, updates

I have a method that adds items to my listbox called refreshInterface which is called as soon as the programe starts, adding names of homeforms in the listbox using the FormItems class, here is the rereshInterface method below

```
    public void refreshInterface()
    {
        //int number = 0;
        foreach (DataSet1.xspGetAnalysisUsageTypesRow homeForms in myDataSet.xspGetAnalysisUsageTypes)
        {
            var forms = new FormItems(homeForms);
            listBox1.Items.Add(forms);
        }
    }
```

The FormItems class is this below

```
public class FormItems
{
    public DataSet1.xspGetAnalysisUsageTypesRow types { get; set; }

    public FormItems(DataSet1.xspGetAnalysisUsageTypesRow usageTypes)
    {
        types = usageTypes;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        // returns the rows that are relating to types.xlib_ID
        var libtyps = types.GetxAnalysisUsageRows();
        var cnt = 0;

        foreach (DataSet1.xAnalysisUsageRow ty in libtyps)
        {
            //returns true if ty is null
            bool typeNull = ty.Isxanu_DefaultNull();

            // if its false, if xanu_Default is set
            if (!typeNull)
            {
                cnt += 1;
            }
        }

        var ret = String.Format("set {0} [Set: {1}]", types.xlib_Desc, cnt);

        //return this.types.xlib_Desc;

        return ret;
    }
}
```

Each listbox (the listbox is on the left of the homeform) item has a number of reports that can be added to it, so for instance, i select an homeform from my listbox, there are 12 textboxes on the right hand side and each textbox has a pair of buttons which are Browse and Clear. If I click on the browse button a new form appears, and i select a report from that form and add it to a particular textbox, the count for that homeform should update, and i clear a textbox for a particular homeform, the count should also update.

At the moment when i debug the application, it shows me the count of each Homeform depending on the amount of reports added to the homeform, but while the programe is running, if i add a new report to a homeform, the count does not update until i restart the debug session. I was told about using a Databinding method but not sure of how i could use it here

How do i ge my listbox item to update ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably look into binding. Here is a good place to start:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140621/WPF-Tutorial-Concept-Binding

If you want a GUI to respond to data changes then binding is your best friend.

Answer (score 0):

You should bind List Box component source to Observable Collection, every update you do to Observable Collection will update List Box data.

Comment: whats the algorithm here? the reason i ask is because i've never used bindin before

Comment: depends if you use XML or programming...research net for details, there is a lots

Answer (score 0):

```
Might not be exact but should give you an idea.

public void refreshInterface()
{
    Dictionary<int,string> items = new Dictionary<int,string>();

    //int number = 0;
    foreach (DataSet1.xspGetAnalysisUsageTypesRow homeForms in myDataSet.xspGetAnalysisUsageTypes)
    {
        var formitem = new FormItems(homeForms);
        items.Add(formitem.someprop, formitem.toString());

    }
    listbox.DataSource = items;
    listbox.DisplayMember = "Value";
    listbox.ValueMember = "Key";
}
```